# How can I get the value of [class.editable] in Angular unit test?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I would like to get the value of the [class.editable] for my unit test.

```
<div class="coolcomponent layout horizontal center" [class.editable]=editable> 
..... 
</div>
```

If I use `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('editable');` my editableEl variable is always null. The same happens with  `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('class.editable')`.

It's part of my unit test, which looks like this:

```
hostComponent.editable = true;
 fixture.detectChanges();
 expect(hostComponent.testComponent.ngOnChanges).toHaveBeenCalled();
 const editableEl = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('class.editable');
 expect(editableEl).toBe(true);
```

Is my selector wrong, or do I need further debugging in my unit test?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: The CSS selector for something with the class of editable is `.editable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like `jonrsharpe` said you don't need `class.`

Try:

```
const editableEl = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('div.editable');
expect(editableEl).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: With `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('div.editable');` I got this: Expected: true
    Received: `<div class="coolcomponent layout horizontal center editable"><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }-->` ... so on. I should get the value of the binding somehow.

Comment: I apologize for that, `.toBe(true)`, means we expect the value of `editableEl` === true but this is false, it will be an object. We should do `.toBeTruthy()` meaning it is a truthy value. I have edited my answer.